# C++ create 2 classes where 2nd class inherits the first class and construction function runs in class which is creating object

Tags: c++

Is this possible to create in C++ or it is impossible?
2 classes-> 2nd class inherits first one and then construction function which runs in the class where Im creating the object.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking whether it's possible to call a constructor function of the base class from the derived class. Is that correct?

Comment: could you please provide some pseudo code, or a more detailed description about your problem. It's not clear what you mean

Comment: Hey, it's university exercise and it's very unclear exercise for me too. Only info which was given to us is: Create two classes, one of which inherits the first. Implement a call to a constructor that is performed only and only in the class that the object is being created.

Comment: That exercise text is terrible. "two classes, one of which inherits the first" is awkward wording, "that is performed only and only in..." is weirdly redundant, the last sentence is missing a word ("being createad **in**."?), and it makes no sense overall (calls are not "performed in a class", what even is "the class that the object is being created"). I recommend requesting clarification. As it stands the question is unclear and not useful.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your comment correctly, you are required to have two classes. One class is derived from the base class. But derived class constructor should call a method which is only part of derived class, but should not be called if you create an instance of Base class.

Simple example showing this:

classes.h

```
class Base{
public:
  Base();
  virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
  Derived();
  virtual ~Derived();

  void task();
};
```

classes.cpp

```
#include "classes.h"

#include <iostream>


Base::Base(){
  std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
}
Base::~Base(){

}

Derived::Derived(){
  std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
  task();
}

Derived::~Derived(){

}

void Derived::task(){
  std::cout << "task" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "classes.h"

int main(void){
  Base base;
  Derived derived;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[me@my_machine]$ ./derived 
Base
Base
Derived
task
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to use virtual destructors?

Comment: @FalcoGer As safety measure for polymorphic use?

Comment: @MaxLanghof could you elaborate that please?
Edit: nvm, I have found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-destructor/

Comment: @FalcoGer If you want to use a class hierarchy in a polymorphic way, you probably want polymorphic deletion (i.e. `delete myPointerToBase;` should call the destructor(s) of the dynamic type, not the static type). A virtual destructor guarantees that.

Comment: Max Langhof is right. It is a safety measure. if you have a Base pointer pointing to a Derived Object I want the Derived destructor to be called when I delete this object.